# jquery insert text to input

Tags: jquery, text, addition

I need to insert some text from 
input text element id="add-tag" to input text element id="show-tag" 
with jQuery

```
<form>
<input name="add-tag" type="text" id="add-tag" />
<button>Send</button>
<hr />
<input name="show-tag" type="text" id="show-tag" />
</form>
```

Comment: It would be better if you could show us what you've tried first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#show-tag').val($('#add-tag').val());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/gHugs/1/)